# Sliced Invoices Contact Form 7 extension: How to populate first & last name fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

How to populate first & last name fields (not only `sliced_invoices_name` field)?

**Plugins**

- [Sliced Invoices & Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sliced-invoices-contact-form-7/)
- [Sliced Invoices – WordPress Invoice Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sliced-invoices/)
- [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Just publishing a solution for adding first & last name to user in **Sliced Invoices Contact Form 7 extension**:

`wp-content\plugins\sliced-invoices-contact-form-7\sliced-invoices-contact-form-7.php`

CHANGE:

`$name       = $posted_data['sliced_client_name'];` // at create_new_quote( $posted_data )

TO:

```
$fname   = $posted_data['sliced_client_fname']; /* REPLACE 'sliced_client_fname' WITH YOUR FIELD NAME IN THE FORM FOR FIRST NAME*/
$lname   = $posted_data['sliced_client_lname']; /* REPLACE 'sliced_client_lname' YOUR FIELD NAME IN THE FORM FOR LAST NAME*/
$name    = $fname . " " . $lname;
```

ADD `fname` and `lname` lines:

```
$client_array = array(
    'name'          => trim( $name ),
    'fname'         => $fname, /* ADDED */
    'lname'         => $lname, /* ADDED */
```

And in `maybe_add_client( $client_array )`

ADD:

```
// create the user
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'  =>  $name,
    'first_name'  =>  $client_array['fname'], /* ADDED */
    'last_name'   =>  $client_array['lname'], /* ADDED */
```

Now you can see the first name & last name fields populated in the "edit client" and "edit profile" views.

WordPress Codex specifies all the fields you can have for a WordPress user (for [`wp_insert_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) function).

Cheers,
Phoebe